# How to get tag list for the website?

Tags: web, tagging

I would like to start a website where data can be tagged. But, I don't how to get that huge list of tags in my database. In stackoverflow.com, if you start typing, you will get options to choose from the list. Is there any open source available to build database like that??

Please let me know.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: There wont be any default database for tags. People make `Tags` out of content on your website & they are used for SEO & better search engine rankings. See wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud)

Answer (score 0):

One option you could try is [screen scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping#Screen_scraping). That involves writing code to actually extract the information you need from an html page.  Obviously, you'd want to adhere to that site's terms of service.